# Creating several objects on form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

What is a good way to create several objects on form submission in Rails? Currently I have a mail 'Share' object, and when it successfully sends out I would like to create a hole new ShareLink object with the identical information, that was passed through the parameters:

```
class SharesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @share = Share.new(params[:share])
    @share.request = request

    respond_to do |format|

    format.js do 
      @share.deliver 
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my Mail object:

```
class Share < MailForm::Base

  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :url
  attribute :message

  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Resource share",
      :to => "#{email}",
      :from => %("John" <1234@gmail.com>)
    }
  end
end
```

I assume that is is not a great idea to pass something like:

```
@share_link = ShareLink.create(params:{...})
```

Right after `@share.delver`, or act through the JS.erb file? Would like to see any thoughts on this.

Comment: I suppose `Share` and `ShareLink` are associated in some manner. If so, use associations to create nested objects. You could add these model schema snippets to your question as well.

Comment: no, unfortunately they are not, because Share is a MailForm base type of object, and it can't take after_create or belongs_to etc.

Comment: Any way, the MCV-idea is that you define a method of Share that handles all your processing, even creating related objects.

Answer (score 0):

If the behaviour you want is "Every time i deliver a Share, I also want to create a ShareLink", then you're right. The controller is not the best place to do this.
Probably would be better to override the `deliver` method in Share so it can insert a new ShareLink

```
def deliver
    super
    ShareLink.create(params:{...})
end
```

But this supposed you have enough information in your `Share` object to create a `ShareLink` one.
This way, even if you create and send `Share`s in other part (maybe automated) of your code, you don;t have to manage this